# DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'numeroGuia'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am a newbie at ASP.net MVC5, my problem is this:

I am creating a partial view "AgregaGuia", in which I make a query to TblGuias model of a row that do not yet have "fechaRecepcionGuia", these guides are filled in a combobox and when selected this the guide fills all textbox in that view. However when running the application it generated the following error: DataBinding : 'System.String' does not Contain a property with the name 'numeroGuia'.

Could anyone help me please??

this is my model:

```
    public partial class TblGuias
    {
        public TblGuias()
        {
            this.TblFactIC = new HashSet<TblFactIC>();
        }

        public string numeroGuia { get; set; }
        public string companiaEnvios { get; set; }
        public string destino { get; set; }
        public decimal pesoGuia { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime fechaEnvioGuia { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> fechaRecepcionGuia { get; set; }
        public string comprobante { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TblFactIC> TblFactIC { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my controller:

```
public class vueInveEntrsController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult AgregaGuia()
    {
        ViewData["guia"] = new SelectList(db.TblGuias.Where(g => g.fechaRecepcionGuia == null).Select((g => g.numeroGuia)),"numeroGuia", "companiaEnvios","destino","pesoGuia","fechaEnvioGuia");
        return PartialView(db.TblGuias.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string numero)
    {
        var query = from c in db.TblGuias
                    where c.numeroGuia == numero
                    select c;
        return Json(query);
    }

}
```

and my view is as follows:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Action", "vueInveEntrs", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Seleccione Guia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("numero", (SelectList)ViewData["guia"], new { onchange = "Action(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Compañia Envios", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("transporte", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Destino", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("destino", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Peso", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("peso", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Fecha Envio", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("fechaenvio", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Action(numero) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "vueInveEntrs")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { "numero": numero },
            "success": function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    var vdata = data;
                    $("#transporte").val(vdata[0].companiaEnvios);
                    $("#destino").val(vdata[0].destino);
                    $("#peso").val(vdata[0].pesoGuia);
                    $("#fechaenvio").val(vdata[0].fechaEnvioGuia);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line in your controller:

```
ViewData["guia"] = new SelectList(
        db.TblGuias.Where(g => g.fechaRecepcionGuia == null).Select((g => g.numeroGuia)),
        "numeroGuia", "companiaEnvios","destino","pesoGuia","fechaEnvioGuia");
```

You are not specifying the constructor parameters for `SelectList` properly.  There are several different overloads, but I think the one you want is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

- The first parameter, `items`, represents the list of items that you want be rendered into `<option>` tags inside the `<select>`.
- The second parameter, `dataValueField`, is the name of the property on the items in the enumerable which will become the `value` attribute inside each `<option>` tag.
- Similarly, the third parameter, `dataTextField`, is the name of the property which will become the text displayed for each `<option>`.

So, if you change your code to the following, I think it should work:

```
ViewData["guia"] = new SelectList(
    db.TblGuias.Where(g => g.fechaRecepcionGuia == null), "numeroGuia", "numeroGuia");
```

If you want different text to display in the dropdown list, change the third parameter to a different property from your `TblGuias` class.